# using rvest (scraping) package and then cleaning the text

Tags: r, rvest, bloomberg

I am trying to us the rvest package to scrape headlines from the bloomberg and cnba websites. Now when you put the bloomberg website through the code, the text and sentences come out well edited. However if you try the cnbc website, it comes out with very unclean text.

Please could anyone suggest a way of cleaning the data so that all the random letters and symbols are removed and I am only left with the sentences. I have tried numerous methods but nothing seems to be working to make the text look clean.

```
#install.packages("rvest")
library("rvest")
#install.packages("XML")
library("XML")
bloombergmarket <- read_html("https://www.bloomberg.com/markets")
databloombergi<-bloombergmarket%>%html_nodes(".module-headline-link")%>%html_text()
databloombergi<-gsub("\\d+","",databloombergi)
databloombergi<-gsub("[[:punct:]]","",databloombergi)

cnbcmarket <- read_html("http://www.cnbc.com/us-news/")
datacnbci<-cnbcmarket%>%html_nodes("div a")%>%html_text()
datacnbci<-gsub("\\d+","",datacnbci)
datacnbci<-gsub("[[:punct:]]","",datacnbci)
```

Answer (score 3):

Working from the `datacnbci` object resulting from the code in your question, it looks like the only cleaning left to do is to clean up whitespace.

```
#replace multiple whitespaces with single space
datacnbci <- gsub('\\s+',' ',datacnbci)
#trim spaces from ends of elements
datacnbci <- trimws(datacnbci)
#drop blank elements
datacnbci <- datacnbci[datacnbci != '']
```

You may want to be more specific then `div a` for your css selector if your goal is to only capture the headlines.  The [Selector Gadget](http://selectorgadget.com/) might be a good tool to get more specific results.

Using a more specific selector:

```
datacnbci <- cnbcmarket %>% 
  html_nodes(".headline a") %>% 
  html_text()

datacnbci <- gsub("\\d+","",datacnbci)
datacnbci <- gsub("[[:punct:]]","",datacnbci)

#replace multiple whitespaces with single space
datacnbci <- gsub('\\s+',' ',datacnbci)
#trim spaces from ends of vector elements
datacnbci <- trimws(datacnbci)
#drop blank elements
datacnbci <- datacnbci[datacnbci != '']
```